# Unable to solve the AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' while trying to apply a function to an entire column in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function, attributeerror

```
def split_address(in_address):
    address = in_address
    address_arr = address.split()

    if len(address_arr):

        for i, w in enumerate(address_arr):
            if w.isnumeric():
                break

        locationName = ' '.join(address_arr[:i])
        locationAddress = ' '.join(address_arr[i:-3])
        locationCity = address_arr[-3]
        locationState = address_arr[-2]
        locationZip = address_arr[-1]

    else:
        locationName.append('')
        locationAddress.append('')
        locationCity.append('')
        locationState.append('')
        locationZip.append('')
        
    return (locationName, locationAddress, locationCity, locationState, locationZip)
new_df = out_df.apply(split_address)
```

The above code throws an error **AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'**

I wish to get an output so that the function is applied on all the rows of the column in the dataframe and the output has to be in 5 different columns as mentioned.

It'd be great if you can please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no need for the loop. Can you share a reproducible example of your dataset and the output desired ?

Comment: `split` is a string method.  `address` isn't a string